# How do I use the main camera (back Camera) in WebCam.js

Tags: webcam.js

I am using webcam.js by https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs and In mobile devices, It's working well  the front camera is opening by default. I can't change it to back Camera, I want to change the default to the Main camera.

Is there any way to change to the main camera device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is so simple, just add this setting row to your page,

```
constraints: { facingMode: 'environment' }
```

it will be like this:

```
Webcam.set({
 width: 640,
 height: 480, 
 image_format: 'jpeg',
 jpeg_quality: 800,
 constraints: { facingMode: 'environment' }
});
```